# Embedding youtube video in webpage for both desktop and iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm surprised I just put object to embed youtube in a wordpress blog and surprise it did play also on ipad.

```
<object width="425" height="344" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoA1MBRJ_BA&amp;hl=de&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"><param name="movie"  value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoA1MBRJ_BA&amp;hl=de&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param></object>
```

Why does it work ? I thought I would need to serve some special code for Ipad ?

I have used real ipad and then Safari with user-agent ipad to get the source code above: how can application/x-shockwave-flash be interpreted as html 5 video ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Ipads and iPhones have a special plugin that replace Youtube flash embeds with H264 video links. So, on the Youtube side doesn't happen nothing. Also, it only works with Youtube (it does not affect Vimeo flash embeds, for example).

Ironically, at the time of writing, the new HTML5 iframe embedding from Youtube doesn't work with the iPhone, nor with the iPad, while the old flash embed still does.

Yes, it's a strange world.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't it work? When youtube detects the iPad user agent it uses HTML5 to serve videos instead of Flash. There's no need to use any special code for iPad as it is capable of rendering normal web pages (except Flash :-)).

Comment: I don't understand how "application/x-shockwave-flash" can interpret html5 video ?

Comment: I have used real ipad and then Safari with user-agent ipad to get the source code above: how can application/x-shockwave-flash be interpreted as html 5 video ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work in iphone

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8VcPF72MFsU?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"/>
```