# Auto close Youtube Video when it's ended on an iPod Touch/iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, web, youtube, ipod

I'm currently doing a mobile website. I have embedded Youtube videos in it.

Thing is, when you open a youtube video in an iPod, it does its thing where it goes full screen, and at the end you must manually close the video to continue browsing.

I was wondering if there is a command to auto-close the fullscreen on the end of the youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what code are you using but I saw this a while ago:

```
<object width="425" height="344" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoA1MBRJ_BA&amp;hl=de&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"><param name="movie"  value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoA1MBRJ_BA&amp;hl=de&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param></object>
```

That is supposed to work flawlessly, source:

[Embedding youtube video in webpage for both desktop and iphone/ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112911/embedding-youtube-video-in-webpage-for-both-desktop-and-iphone-ipad)

Comment: I tried that code, and the video just didn't show up anymore... Well it looked promising thanks!
I use the new embed code BTW. My theory is that the ipod is doing his own stuff with the video, so I cant reach it.
Thanks anyway.